# How to build an API mashup using Node.js and Express?

Tags: ios, node.js, api, express, backend

I’m working on an iOS app that aggregates contents (i.e. events) from different services (Google Calendar, Basecamp…) using their REST APIs.

Instead of querying these services in the client, I wonder if it wouldn’t make more sense to do it server side. This would allow me to unify the different models beforehand, reduce the client side logic significantly, and IMO make it both more scalable and easier to maintain.

But I have no experience of this kind of backend and no idea where to start, or even if it’s a good idea at all? Do you have any idea? I was thinking of using Node.js and Express/LoopBack…

Thank you in advance for your help!

David

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this question will be soon marked as opinionated, and myself most likely be down voted... but maybe I will be on time to pass a little of my experience working on a back-end for my employer.

If you do not need to impose any control over who and when and what data is being pulled from those multiple external services it makes more sense to free yourself from the hurdle of developing and maintaining your own back end. Keep in mind the costs associated with having to support your own servers...

Additionally, having this logic on the client scales proportionate to the external services being used while with your own back end you will have to make sure that it is programmed to scale well, which could be a considerable undertaking if you never did it (not saying that it is impossible to learn in a reasonable timeframe).

Basically, what I am saying is it is always better to delegate security/control agnostic logic to the client side. This way by the way, you will be following along the lines of currently buzzing micro-services trend :)

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I certainly won't downvote your answer, as I'm looking for opinionated advices. Thanks a lot for your answer! ;)